# HAProxy reload issue in cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, haproxy

I have this problem with reloading the HAProxy using this command:

```
haproxy -D -f gateway.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -D -sf $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid)
```

The error result

```
[ALERT] 169/001728 (3844) : Starting frontend proxy: cannot bind socket
```

I have tried adding user root or Administrator in the config but to no avail. The file permission according to ls -la is `Administrator none`. It makes me think HAProxy does not completely support windows and I wonder how does -sf/-st prefix work? (I tried in unix system and it turns out working correctly. The HAProxy config is shown below

```
global  
daemon
maxconn 1024
pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid

defaults
log global
mode    http
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
retries 3
option redispatch
contimeout  5000
clitimeout  50000
srvtimeout  50000

frontend proxy
bind *:80
default_backend servers

backend servers
balance roundrobin
option httpchk GET /
option forwardfor
option httpclose
stats enable
stats refresh 10s
stats hide-version
stats uri /admin?stats
stats auth admin:admin
stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics

server svr0 127.0.0.1 check inter 5000
```

Comment: To use HAProxy, we requires Linux/Ubuntu servers? Can we run & utilize over Windows Server 2000 environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAProxy generally does not support Windows, even under Cygwin. HAProxy contains very specific optimisations for Linux and a variety of UNIX systems which make it very hard to be able to run it on Windows.

And even if you would somehow make it run, it would result in abysmal performance and would never get a stable or even moderately fast system. It just doesn't make any sense to run HAProxy on Windows and trying to deal with various emulation layers when you get great performance even out of a sub-1-Watt ARM box running on Linux.

Comment: It is for measurement purposes. I guess I will need to change to linux system after all..

Comment: To use HAProxy, we requires Linux/Ubuntu servers? Can we run & utilize over Windows Server 2000 environment?

Comment: @iamtheladylegend HAProxy runs best on Linux. It is also tested and used on a rather large amount of other UNIX systems (e.g FreeBSD, OpenBSD, Solaris, AIX). HAProxy does not support Windows as a host OS.

Answer (score -1):

You can run most of haproxy version under windows. Here is the 1.4.24 compilated using cygwin:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/7l4yg7fa5w185bo/haproxy.zip

You can use it for testing purpose, but you should avoid production with it, only to be able to develop under windows with an easy transfert to linux for example...

Comment: This link looks shady. Don't download that!